Retrieving products based on pre-existing filters, the fastest way possible
Introduction and case scenario
I am developing a microservice for our project, which is going to handle a section named 'custom categories'. The scenario for this part is this:
1- Define the custom category
First, the site admin creates a custom category, e.g., 'women leather boots'. Doing so, the admin then selects criteria that determine what products would be in this custom category, e.g., the admin first selects the gender filter and chooses female for gender, then chooses the material filter, selects leather for this filter, and finally, from the category fields, selects boot.
2- Filter the products based on the pre-defined custom category
Now that the admin has created the custom category, users will see it on the front-end site and can select it from the categories menu to more easily access their desired groups of products. What happens in the backend is that, based on the filters defined by the admin, we go through the db and filter the products based on those criteria, then return the results in a paginated manner. In the process, we also extract filters based on the products so that users can also filter the results even more using desired attributes or other properties of the products.
What are the challenges?
The described scenario is written in PHP, using PHP Laravel and PostgreSQL together, which has a lot of problems regarding performance. Thus, I come here to develop this using FastAPI as my framework to handle large numbers of concurrent requests and Qdrant as my DB to handle AI-based recommendations.
In the new version, this 'recommendation' part is being added, and this is more or less how it is going to work: now that the data has been filtered regarding the criteria and filters selected, we will add one more layer of refinement to better suit the results for the user based on their browsing and click history on our website.
Also, speed-wise, the situation is very sensitive here. I need to be able to handle large amounts of requests while also answering them in 300-400 ms.
What should I use?
Now, what stacks and techs should I use here? Is my plan to use FastAPI and Qdrant a good plan here? What about MongoDB? I know that I am going to need a vector database with a fast recommendation API to be able to sort the results based on their similarities to the user's browsing history. So, I am guessing I should stick with Qdrant, but still, I am not sure of the structure and the architecture here. Any tips, suggestions, links, docs, examples, git repos, all kinds of help are deeply appreciated.

In order to ensure a robust and scalable system, it is crucial to prioritize system design. By investing time and effort into system design, you can enjoy the peace of mind of not having to worry about adding new features or functionalities to your system in the future.
I found an informative article titled "System Design for Recommendations and Search" available at:

https://eugeneyan.com/writing/system-design-for-discovery/

This article provides a comprehensive overview of system design techniques and concepts that are specifically relevant for implementing Search and Recommendation Systems. It covers fundamental principles, best practices, and provides links to additional resources that will further support you on your journey.
I hope you find this resource valuable and wish you success in your endeavors.

This was a great article, thank you for sharing. I read it, and I am happy that at least my search service is correct (at least pattern wise), and I just face speed problems in my api. This re-ranking stage mentioned in this article, I am using BAAI/bge-reranker-v2-m3 model (https://huggingface.co/BAAI/bge-reranker-v2-m3), but for 50 pairs of query-product_title it takes more than 1 second, which is disastrous speed wise. I tried looking for every possible flaw in my design, and yet not able to find a solution.
